# log4net doesnt give any response or logging

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I'm trying to use log4net to write errors to a file. I get no errors and no logfile. What am I missing here?

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
```

```
<log4net>
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="c:\Temp\testlog4net.txt" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
    <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

code:

```
private static ILog _fileLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogHelper));

public static void Error(Exception e)
    {
        _fileLogger.Error(e);
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the windows event log? And is the user running the application allowed to create a file in that location?

Comment: Nothing in the eventlog.. And I am running the site as my self (local admin)

Comment: What type of application your are developing? See [this](http://www.codeandyou.com/2015/02/how-to-use-log4net-in-aspnet-mvc.html) how to use page.

Comment: it is a web page, not using MVC but Forms

Comment: Do I need to register it somewhere? Like in AssemblyInfo.cs or something?

Comment: Yes, you do need to initialize logging: it looks like your logging config is in an a web.config file, so you can just call `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` at startup to load it.

Comment: Thanks! If your wright it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this to

> AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```